# Use induction to show that $a_{n+1}-a_n=\biggl(-\frac{1}{2} \biggr)^n (a_1-a_0) .$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

> Let $a_0$ and $a_1$ be distinct real numbers. Define
>   $a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2}$ for each positive integer $n\geq 2$. Prove that $$a_{n+1}-a_n=\biggl(-\frac{1}{2} \biggr)^n (a_1-a_0) $$

This is what I have so far:

> Let $P(n)$ be the statement: For all $n\geq 2$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $$
>  a_{n+1}-a_n=\biggl(-\frac{1}{2} \biggr)^n (a_1-a_0). $$ We must show
>    1. $P(2)$ holds, 2. For all $k\geq 2$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, if $P(k)$ holds, then $P(k+1)$ holds. Let $n=2$. Then   $$  \begin{aligned}
>  a_{n+1}-a_n &=a_3-a_2\\  &=\frac{a_2+a_1}{2}-\frac{a_1+a_0}{2}\\
>  &=\frac{a_1+a_0+2a_1}{4}-\frac{a_1+a_0}{2}\\
>  &=\frac{3a_1+a_0}{4}+\frac{-2a_1-2a_0}{4}\\  &=\frac{a_1-a_0}{4}\\
>  &=\biggl(-\frac{1}{2}\biggr)^2(a_1-a_0).  \end{aligned}  $$    Hence,
>   $P(2)$ holds.   Suppose that for all $k\geq 2$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$,
>   $P(k)$ holds, that is   $$  \begin{aligned}  a_{k+1}-a_k
>  &=\frac{a_k+a_{k-1}}{2}-\frac{a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}}{2}\\ 
>   &=\biggl(-\frac{1}{2} \biggr)^k (a_1-a_0).  \end{aligned}  $$    Then
>       $$  \begin{aligned}  a_{(k+1)+1}-a_{k+1} &=a_{k+2}-a_{k+1}\\
>   &=\frac{a_{k+1}+a_k}{2}-\frac{a_k+a_{k-1}}{2}\\
>   &=\frac{a_k+a_{k-1}+a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}}{4}-\frac{a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}+a_{k-2}+a_{k-3}}{4}\\  &=\biggl(\frac{a_k+a_{k-1}-a_{k-2}-a_{k-3}}{2}\biggr)^2\\
>  &=\frac{a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}+a_{k-2}+a_{k-3}-a_{k-3}-a_{k-4}-a_{k-4}-a_{k-5}}{8}\\
>  &=\biggl(\frac{a_{k-1}+2a_{k-2}-2a_{k-4}-a_{k-5}}{2}\biggr)^3
>  \end{aligned}  $$

Ok, so here it seems that I will just end up substituting forever. I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: As an alternative approach, you could try finding and proving what the limit of the sequence is. (I recommend playing around with some simple $a_0,a_1$ to get a sense for the pattern.)

Comment: I suggest writing a few terms out and you will see a pattern forming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Subtract $a_{n-1}$ from both sides. We get
$$a_n-a_{n-1}=-\frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}).$$
The "new difference" is the "old difference" times $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite seeing your point. When I subtract $a_{n-1}$ from both sides I get $\frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}-a_{n-3})$. Please give me a little more detail, if you don't mind.

Comment: @Skull-Face If you start with $a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2}$ and subtract $a_{n-1}$ from both sides, then $a_{n-3}$ does not show up.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Ok, I see what's going on. When I subtracted $a_{n-1}$, I was doing $a_n-a_{n-1}=\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2}-\frac{a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}}{2}$ instead of $a_n-a_{n-1}=\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2}-\frac{2a_{n-1}}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the induction hypothesis (with two base cases) immediately after your second equality when computing $a_{k + 1} - a_{k + 1}$, for we then have

\begin{align*}
\frac{a_{k + 1} + a_k}{2} - \frac{a_k + a_{k - 1}}{2} &= \frac 1 2\left(- \frac 1 2\right)^k (a_1 - a_0) - \frac 1 2\left(-\frac 1 2\right)^{k - 1} (a_1 - a_0) \\
&= (-1)^k \left(\frac{1}{2^{k + 1}} - \frac 1 {2^k}\right) (a_1 - a_0) \\
&= (-1)^k \left(-\frac{1}{2^{k + 1}}\right) (a_1 - a_0) \\
&= \left(-\frac 1 2 \right)^{k + 1} (a_1 - a_0)
\end{align*}

as desired.